# asp.NET Razor Pages dropdownlist from DB form

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, list, razor-pages

I'm writing Library Application (adding,deleting) books from db.
I'm using Razor Pages .NET CORE 2.2
I added dropdownlist to my project and now when i hit submit button in my form, nothing is added to database and i don't know why...
Any ideas?

My code:

1) Genre.cs

```
namespace BIBL.Model

public class Genre
{
    [Key]
    public int GenreID { get; set; }

    public string GenreName { get; set; }
```

}

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
namespace BIBL.Data

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Book> Book { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FavBook> FavBook { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genre> Genre { get; set; }

}
```

}

And razor page where i'm adding book.

AddBook.cshtml.cs

```
public class AddBookModel : PageModel
{

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    [BindProperty]
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public int SelectedGenreId { set; get; }

    public List<SelectListItem> GenreItems { set; get; }



    public AddBookModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        GenreItems = _db.Genre
                               .Select(a => new SelectListItem
                               {
                                   Value = a.GenreID.ToString(),
                                   Text = a.GenreName
                               })
                              .ToList();
        return Page();
    }






    public async Task <IActionResult> OnPostAsync(ServiceType ServiceType)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
            var selectedGenreId = this.SelectedGenreId;
        }

        _db.Book.Add(Book);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("Index");

    }
```

Then AddBook.cshtml

```
<div class="col-5">
            <select asp-for="SelectedGenreId" asp-items="@Model.GenreItems">
                <option>Select one</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: You are passing in a `ServiceType` to your post method, yet you add a book, which you have not used in any way or form. How is `Book` populated?

Comment: So what should i change ?

Comment: There is no way to tell. You are not showing us, how you actually create a book in your markup and how you post it to the server. We don't know what a `ServiceType` is. There are too many possibilities to know what is wrong.

Comment: ServiceType is empty. I don't have any code there.

Comment: What do you expect to see added to the database?